# How do i get the mouse position to a part in roblox?

Tags: position, mouse, roblox

**I truly want to know. How do i get the mouse position to a part in roblox? Like, i want to get the mouse position, on screen, aligned with a part. Let's say the part position is 10,10,10 and i want my mouse to point at that exact position, how can i do that? (I just need to get the position, ex: 1093x899, 1789x305. Didn't understand? Here, i simply want to know the position, on which my mouse would say that there is the 'part' that i want my mouse to point at. Any help is nice!**

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do? Are you just trying to get the screen coordinates of an object? Are you trying to click on the object? Is this for a Roblox script or something that works with the Roblox client?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs for [Camera:WorldToScreenPoint](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Camera/WorldToScreenPoint).

I've adapted the code sample from there:

```
local camera = workspace.CurrentCamera

-- get the position of the part you care about
local targetPart = game.Workspace.YOUR_PART_NAME
local worldPoint = targetPart.Position

-- get the screen coordinates
local vector, onScreen = camera:WorldToScreenPoint(worldPoint)
if onScreen then
    local screenPoint = Vector2.new(vector.X, vector.Y)
    print(screenPoint)
else
    print("the part isn't on your screen right now")
end
```

You'll need to hook this up to a loop of some kind to repeated get the coordinates.